# Excel sum top N values in row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am an excel formula novice and am currently struggling with a formula to sum the top 4 values in a specific row.

[image]

Any help

Comment: Google for "excel top n" to find your answer

Comment: Please show some effort of what you have tried thusfar

Answer (score 1):

To to that you could use a SUM combined with LARGE function. For example:
`=SUM(LARGE(B3:F3,{1,2,3,4}))`
Result will be: `1079`
NOTE: Adjust the array {1,2,3,4,5} to sum top 5 numbers.